# VBA actions based on cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to organize information that I copied into an excel sheet so that I can sort through it better.  It it starts out in one column like an outline, but without bullets, and I want to put the sub-information in columns next to the main information.

**Macro purpose:**
*From:*

---

SUM function

Description of SUM

IF function

Description of IF function

DATE function

Description of DATE function

Second description of DATE function

DAYS function

Description of DAYS function

FIND, FINDB functions

Description of FIND, FINDB

INDEX function

Description of INDEX function

---

*To:*

---

SUM function . . . . . . . . Description of SUM
IF function . . . . . . . . . . . Description of IF function
DATE function . . . . . . . . Description of DATE function
 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Second description of DATE function
DAYS function . . . . . . . . Description of DAYS function
FIND, FINDB functions . Description of FIND, FINDB
INDEX function . . . . . . . Description of INDEX function

---

I think what I have should work, but I keep getting either an error 91 or 1004 while trying to shift the sub-info right.

**Problem code:**

```
' Shift sub-info right
Dim r As Integer
Dim find As String
find = "* function"

Range("A1").Select
For r = 1 To row1
    If Range(ActiveCell).find(What:=find, Lookat:=xlWhole).Select Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    End If
Next r
```

I am just starting to learn VBA so my code may be elementary, but I am thinking that my problems is that ".find" is not a boolean expression and I don't know an equivalent funtion that is boolean, or how to convert it to one.

Maybe there is a way to do it all at once instead of using "for, to, next" function, but I would have no idea on how to start.

**Full code:**

```
Sub Shift_Over()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1
Dim n As Integer

'Locate last used cell
Range("A1:A8").Select
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(8).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(7)).Select
    row = row + 8
Loop

Rows(row).Select

Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Rows(row - 1).Select
    row = row - 1
Loop

' Remove unneded rows
Dim row1 As Integer
row1 = 1

For n = 1 To row - 1
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        Rows(row - 1).Select
        row = row - 1
        row1 = row1 + 1
    Else
        Rows(row).Delete
        Rows(row - 1).Select
        row = row - 1
    End If
Next n

' Check value of row1
Rows(row1).Select

' Shift sub-info right
Dim r As Integer
Dim find As String
find = "* function"

Range("A1").Select
For r = 1 To row1
    If Range(ActiveCell).find(What:=find, Lookat:=xlWhole).Select Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    End If
Next r

'move sub-info in line with main-info
Range("B1").Delete (xlShiftUp)
Dim row2 As Integer
row2 = row1 + 5

Rows(row2).Select
Do While IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Rows(row2 - 1).Select
    row2 = row2 - 1
Loop

'remove unneeded rows
Dim d As Integer
Dim lines As Integer
lines = 1

For r = 1 To row2 - 1
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        Rows(row2 - 1).Select
        row2 = row2 - 1
        lines = lines + 1
    Else
        Rows(row2).Delete
        Rows(row2 - 1).Select
        row2 = row2 - 1
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Also, as I am learning, If you have ideas on how to make my code more efficient (improve it), or if there are any nuances about programming that you notice I don't know, I would be glad to hear it.

I just realized that not all of my code is doing what I thought it would.  Instead of looking at the entire selection, it it is only looking at the active cell.  I tried replacing "IsEmpty(ActiveCell)" with "IsEmpty(Selection)" but it would act as if everything had text in it.  However as it is, if there are two sets of sub-info, then the second one will be deleted. (The fourth line of the example would be deleted)

```
'remove unneeded rows
Dim d As Integer
Dim lines As Integer
lines = 1

For r = 1 To row2 - 1
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
        Rows(row2 - 1).Select
        row2 = row2 - 1
        lines = lines + 1
    Else
        Rows(row2).Delete
        Rows(row2 - 1).Select
        row2 = row2 - 1
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: What is differentiating the function names from the function descriptions? For example, do only the function names have the word function in them?

Comment: The actual description was too long to put all of them in, but one example is "SUM function" -- "Use this function to add the values in cells." They all have the first word in all caps followed by the single word "function." I tried to limit the find function by using "xlWhole" instead of "xlParts."

Comment: Ok so the function names always start with at least three capital letters? Are there blank rows interspersed throughout the data?

Comment: When I start there is, but the first few steps of the macro are to remove those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done much simpler by avoiding the select statement. In general, when manipulating things in Excel you want to avoid Select because it slows things down and it can make your code harder to maintain.

The below code loops through the first 500 rows in Column A. If it finds a blank row, it deletes that row. In this simplistic case, I just tested whether cells A + B were both empty. If row isn't empty, it checks whether the first three letters are capitalized. If they aren't, it must be a description row, so it moves the cell contents to column B.

```
Sub Shift_Over2()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 500 To 1 step -1 
        If Range("A" & i).Value = "" And Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        ElseIf UCase(Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 3)) <> Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 3) Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            Range("A" & i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The reason your code couldn't run was because you were trying to use the find function (which returns a range) as a boolean (true/false). However even after fixing that issue, it still wouldn't work as intended because it would treat any description that had the word "function" in it as a function name.